# JSON decoding error when Posting to Spring Boot 2 Custom Endpoint

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Custom Endpoints with Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE

I have my custom endpoint as below,

```
@Endpoint(id = "mycaches" ,enableByDefault=true)
@Component
public class CacheEndpoint {
@WriteOperation
    public String invalidateCacheKeys(@Selector String arg0,List<String> cacheList) {
        System.out.println(cacheList);
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to receive a collection of keys and process them accordingly.

When I am trying to submit the request through rest client as below

```
[
"1","2","3"
]
```

I get the below error.

```
Response status 400 with reason "Failed to read HTTP message"; nested exception is org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
```

If I submit with the below input,

```
 {
    "cacheList": ["1","2","3"]
}
```

I get the below error,

```
 Response status 400 with reason "Failed to read HTTP message"; nested exception is org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["cacheList"])
```

Can someone help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same; I believe the issue here is that JSON arrays are not supported.

The reference docs here don't explicitly state it, but they strongly convey it's only simple key/value pairs that may be posted: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-custom-input

Posting: "1,2,3" as a simple string to parse/split in your own code might work instead.

(NB I know I am posting this 5 years too late, but in case it helps others...)